# Matchcollection Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm trying to create a Parallel.Foreach loop for matchcollection.
It's in  a scraper I built.
I just need to know what to put in the Parallel.Foreach

```
MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches(htmlcon, matchlink, RegexOptions.Singleline);

                Parallel.ForEach(WHAT DO I PUT HERE? =>
                {

                        Get(match.Groups[1].Value, false);
                        Match fname = Regex.Match(htmlcon, @"<span class=""given-name"(.*?)</span>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
                        Match lname = Regex.Match(htmlcon, @"span class=""family-name"">(.*?)</span>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

                        firstname = fname.Groups[1].Value;
                        lastname = lname.Groups[1].Value;

                        sw.WriteLine(firstname + "," + lastname);
                        sw.Flush();

                }):
```

I tried:

```
Parallel.ForEach<MatchCollection>(m,match  =>
```

but no luck!

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because `Parallel.ForEach` is expecting a generic `IEnumerable` and `MatchCollection` only implements the non generic one.

Try this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    m.OfType<Match>(),
    (match) =>
    {
    );
```