# Parallel.ForEach with MatchCollection

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

First off, I know this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788972/matchcollection-parallel-foreach), but I can't get the solution listed there to work for me.  I understand that MatchCollection does not implement the IEnumerable Parallel.ForEach uses, and thus the need for OfType()... any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Here's my setup:

```
MatchCollection startMatches = Regex.Matches(tempRTB.Text, startPattern);

System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(startMatches.OfType<Match>, m =>
{
    // do stuff with m
});
```

And here's the compile error I get:

```
Error   11  The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Action<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Comment: Note that `MatchCollection`'s elements are always `Match`, so you can just use `.Cast<Match>()` instead of `OfType`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you are missing is `()` (OfType is a static extension method)

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(startMatches.OfType<Match>(), m =>
        {
            // do stuff with m
        });
```